# How can I update Eclipse ADT plugin to 24

Tags: eclipse-adt, android-sdk-manager

This morning I updated the Android SDK Tool to 24, it needs ADT 24 , but nothing can be updated in Eclipse. What could I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddy, just **set down** the Android Version to use when rendering layout in Eclipse.

Eg: set API to 21 or lower...

Here is a snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Good idea.  ADT 23 is the latest Version , I need migrate the project to Android Studio. : )

Answer (score 1):

The one of last is [adt-24.0.2.zip](http://dl.google.com/dl/android/adt-24.0.2.zip). This was created for resolving some [issues](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82393).

Answer (score 0):

Download ADT: http://dl.google.com/dl/android/adt-24.0.2.zip

Follow Below Steps in your eclipse :

1.In Eclipse go to Help

2.Install New Software ---> Add

3.inside Add Repository write the Name: ADT (or whatever you want)

4.Select Your Downloaded zip file

5.click Next

6.Finish

Find Attached screenshot for your reference 
[image]